# Assign multiple params from single (singleton) select in Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

In a Firebird execute block I want to execute a singleton select and assign multiple columns to a set of parameters/variables. I know a single value can be assigned with `:param = (select ...)` and that I can also loop through a result set and assign multiple params with `for select ... into :p1, :p2...`.

But I don't want a loop, because it's a singleton select, but I do want to assign multiple parameters from that select.

How is that done?

Comment: Found it: you can do `select ... into :p1, :p2...` without the `for`, i.e. without looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`select .. into`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-select-into):

```
execute block returns (a integer, b integer)
as
begin
  select 1, 2 from rdb$database into a, b;
end
```

In the `into` clause, it is not necessary to prefix the variables with `:`.

Depending on the client used, you may also need to include a `suspend` after the `select` statement to see the values in the client.